# Show error in new HTML element without page refresh

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to create a comment section for my website and need to make it so that after the person submits a comment (and it contains errors), it will show the error (a new HTML element) without refreshing the page. I know almost nothing of AJAX/JQuery, so I'll need some help.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['reply_submit'])) {
    $reply = $_POST['new_reply'];
    $reply_message = "";

    if(empty($reply)) {
      $reply_message = "Your comment is too short.";
    }
  }
?>

<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <form class="no-margin" method="POST" action="">
      <textarea name="new_reply" placeholder="Write a reply..."></textarea>
      <button name="reply_submit" class="btn post-button" type="submit">Post' . (isset($reply_message) ? '<div class="comment-warning">' . $reply_message . '</div>' : '') . '</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

So what I need it to do is, if the person's comment box doesn't meet the criteria (in this case, an empty field), I need it to show this error line without refreshing the page:

```
<button name="reply_submit" class="btn post-button" type="submit">Post' . (isset($reply_message) ? '<div class="comment-warning">' . $reply_message . '</div>' : '') . '</button>
```

Please help.

Comment: you should use js for this, then do a sever side check that also does the same check, so js check, ajax post, php check, js error return.

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times.

Comment: continuing to do this will result in you being blocked from asking questions at all.

Answer (score 0):

> **HTML** mostly the same, add onsubmit action

```
<form class="no-margin" method="POST" action="" onsubmit=verify();>
      <textarea name="new_reply" id="new_reply_textarea" placeholder="Write a reply..."></textarea>
...
</form>
<div class=comment-warning></div>
```

> **JS**

```
function verify()
{
if ($('#new_reply_textarea').is(':empty'))
{
$('.comment-warning').html("Your comment is too short.");
return false;
}
else
{
return true;
}
}
```